# Zend 1.10 place websites in virtual subdirectories

Tags: apache, zend-framework, url-rewriting, routes, alias

I have the following situation: 
We have a webapp built with Zend Framework 1.10 that is available under **www.domain.com/webapp**

On the server filesystem, we really also have the webapp deployed in **/srv/www/webapp**

Now, for some reasons I can't detail too much, the project manager has requested, now that the app is finished, that each client recieves his own url litteraly. 
So we would have:
www.domain.com/webapp/**client1**
www.domain.com/webapp/**client2**

Normally, what start after the webapp/ would be the controllers, actions and so forth from zend.

Therefore the question: is there a quick way in apache to create these virtual subdirectories, as in the example, client1, client2 ?

I guess it should be possible with url rewriting ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks, I did have a look but I am really confused as how to solve this actually

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating virtual directories, this can be solved by creating a specific route with [`Zend_Route`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.standard). Assuming, controller as `User` and the action to pass the name would be `view`, then

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'webapp/:username',
    array(
        'controller' => 'user',
        'action'     => 'view',
        'username'   => 'defaultuser'
    )
);
```

Comment: Ok I see. But now I have like 150 actions over 3 controllers. I probably shouldn't create a route for each. Is there a way to express the same thing but with wildcard, i.e, to say something like "please put the webapps/username prefix for every possible combination?". Also, should the route setup be done in index.php or in the bootstrap ? In anay case thanks!

Comment: `:username` above is the wild card

Comment: Oh ok sorry, I'll post what I have until now

Comment: I have this in the boostrap: $router->addRoute('subdirectory',new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('webapp/:username'));  Still not working

Comment: Calling the script with the url domain/webapp/client1, but it says as error: 'Zend_Controller_Router_Exception' with message 'username is not specified'

Comment: @Julien, It should not be, have you used, exactly what i gave?

Comment: Yes, I added this with $router->addRoute() in the Bootstrap.

Comment: I don't understand; is there an update route method ? I can't find it.